# Gate closure is always denied

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I've been able to create policy classes but when I try to register a gate closure, it is always denied.

Here is the `boot()` method in AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('view-admin-index', function ($user, $company) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Here is the output when dumped.

```
dd(Gate::has('view-admin-index')); => true
dd(Gate::allows('view-admin-index', $company)); => false
```

**UPDATE**

I also get `false` instead of `"here"` if do this:

```
// In AuthServiceProvider
Gate::define('view-admin-index', function ($user, $company) {
    dd('here');
    return true;
});

// In controller, output is false
dd(Gate::allows('view-admin-index', $company));
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
// In controller, there is an authenticated user and output is false
dd(auth()->user()); // => User
dd(Gate::allows('view-admin-index', $company)); // => false
```

Comment: What's the output when you `dd()` from inside the closure?

Comment: I updated my answer to show what happens when I `dd()` inside the `Gate` closure

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't even getting to call the closure. This will be the behavior if you don't have a user currently authenticated. See [Source Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L234).  Are you getting any output if you call `dd(Auth::user())` right before `Gate::allows('view-admin-index', $company)`?

If you need to manually login a user you can always do:

```
Auth::login(User::find($id));
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show that the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it looks like a big bug of Laravel 5.3.28. 
It just doesn't accepts Collections as arguments. 
Here is my workaround:

Code:

```
Gate::define('xx', function ($auth, $user) {
    return 1;
});

Route::get('example', function()
{
    $user = User::first();
    dd( Gate::allows('xx', $user) ); //false
});
```

My workaround:

```
Route::get('example', function()
{
    $user = (object)User::first()->toArray();
    dd( Gate::allows('xx', $user) ); //true
});
```